# Show Latest Channel Entries Under Single Entrey

Tags: channel

I'm trying to show the latest 5 entries in a channel, when a user views an entry within the channel.

At the moment, the code will only show the info for the single entry in both sections. My code is below;

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-2-3">
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="news" 
    require_entry="yes"
}
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-3">
        <h2>Top News</h2>
        <ul class="news-headlines">
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="news" 
    orderby="entry_date" 
    sort="desc" 
    limit="5"
}
            <li class="item">
                <h3><a href="{url_title_path=" ee/news-article"}">{title} </a> </h3>
                <p>{excerpt}</p>
            </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `dynamic="no"` to the channel entries tag.